# Logic App deployed via ARM Template with custom connector (SOAP Passthrough) not configured properly

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have a logic app which contains an action that is using a custom connector. Custom connector is a SOAP Pass through.

Everything is being deployd via ARM Template. When I deploy, everything looks OK except the action for custom connector. It says 'Connector not found'. But If i delete that and add a new action from Logic App designer, everything seems to work as it should. So I believe, the custom connector and api connections are being setup properly but for some reason the action is not setup properly.

Connector is a SOAP Passthrough configured to use on-premises data gateway.

[image]

Here is ARM Template (I have removed sensitive information)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "logicAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Logic App."
      },
      "defaultValue": "TestLogicAppCustomConnector"
    },
    "logicAppLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "allowedValues": [
        "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "eastasia",
        "southeastasia",
        "centralus",
        "eastus",
        "eastus2",
        "westus",
        "northcentralus",
        "southcentralus",
        "northeurope",
        "westeurope",
        "japanwest",
        "japaneast",
        "brazilsouth",
        "australiaeast",
        "australiasoutheast",
        "southindia",
        "centralindia",
        "westindia",
        "canadacentral",
        "canadaeast",
        "uksouth",
        "ukwest",
        "westcentralus",
        "westus2"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location of the Logic App."
      }
    },
    "customApis_RemedyConnector_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "remedyconnector"
    },
    "connections_RemedyConnector_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "RemedyPassThroughConnection"
    },
    "connections_RemedyConnector_DisplayName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Remedy PassThrough SOAP Connection"
    },
    "remedy_Host": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "server.company.com:8080"
    },
    "remedy_Base_Path": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "/service"
    },
    "remedy_username": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "username"
    },
    "remedy_password": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "pwd"
    },
    "onPremDataGateway_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "on-prem-gateway"
    },
    "onPremDataGatewayRG_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "gateway-rg"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "remedy_webservice_full_url": "[concat('http://',parameters('remedy_Host'),parameters('remedy_Base_Path'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/customApis",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('customApis_RemedyConnector_name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "RemedyCustomConnector"
      },
      "properties": {
        "connectionParameters": {
          "username": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "uiDefinition": {
              "displayName": "userName",
              "description": "The userName for this api",
              "tooltip": "Provide the userName",
              "constraints": {
                "tabIndex": 2,
                "clearText": true,
                "required": "true",
                "capability": [
                  "gateway"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "password": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "uiDefinition": {
              "displayName": "password",
              "description": "The password for this api",
              "tooltip": "Provide the password",
              "constraints": {
                "tabIndex": 3,
                "clearText": false,
                "required": "true",
                "capability": [
                  "gateway"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "authType": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
              {
                "value": "basic"
              }
            ],
            "uiDefinition": {
              "displayName": "Authentication Type",
              "description": "Authentication type to connect to your API",
              "tooltip": "Authentication type to connect to your API",
              "constraints": {
                "tabIndex": 1,
                "required": "true",
                "allowedValues": [
                  {
                    "text": "basic",
                    "value": "basic"
                  }
                ],
                "capability": [
                  "gateway"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "gateway": {
            "type": "gatewaySetting",
            "gatewaySettings": {
              "dataSourceType": "CustomConnector",
              "connectionDetails": []
            },
            "uiDefinition": {
              "constraints": {
                "tabIndex": 4,
                "required": "true",
                "capability": [
                  "gateway"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "description": "SOAP pass-through for Remedy Calls",
        "displayName": "[parameters('customApis_RemedyConnector_name')]",
        "backendService": {
          "serviceUrl": "[variables('remedy_webservice_full_url')]"
        },
        "apiType": "Soap",
        "wsdlDefinition": {
          "importMethod": "SoapPassThrough"
        },
        "capabilities": [
          "gateway"
        ],
        "swagger": {
          "swagger": "2.0",
          "info": {
            "title": "SOAP pass-through",
            "description": "SOAP pass-through for Remedy Calls",
            "version": "1.0"
          },
          "host": "[parameters('remedy_Host')]",
          "basePath": "[parameters('remedy_Base_Path')]",
          "consumes": [],
          "produces": [],
          "paths": {
            "/SoapPassThrough": {
              "post": {
                "operationId": "SoapPassThrough",
                "parameters": [
                  {
                    "name": "server",
                    "in": "query",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "servername",
                    "x-ms-visibility": "important",
                    "enum": [
                      "servername"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "webService",
                    "in": "query",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "FRIntegration",
                    "x-ms-visibility": "important",
                    "enum": [
                      "FRIntegration"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Content-Type",
                    "in": "header",
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "text/xml",
                    "enum": [
                      "text/xml"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "SOAPAction",
                    "in": "header",
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "urn:FRIntegration/OpCreate",
                    "enum": [
                      "urn:FRIntegration/OpCreate"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "body",
                    "in": "body",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {},
                      "x-ms-visibility": "important"
                    },
                    "x-ms-visibility": "important"
                  }
                ],
                "responses": {
                  "200": {
                    "description": "OK"
                  }
                },
                "summary": "Update",
                "description": "Update Remedy Record",
                "x-ms-visibility": "important"
              }
            }
          },
          "definitions": {},
          "parameters": {},
          "responses": {},
          "securityDefinitions": {
            "basic_auth": {
              "type": "basic"
            }
          },
          "security": [],
          "tags": [],
          "schemes": [
            "http"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('connections_RemedyConnector_name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "RemedyConnection"
      },
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/customApis', parameters('customApis_RemedyConnector_name'))]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('connections_RemedyConnector_DisplayName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "authType": "Basic",
          "userName": "[parameters('remedy_username')]",
          "password": "[parameters('remedy_password')]",
          "gateway": {
            "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/',parameters('onPremDataGatewayRG_name'),'/providers/Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways/',parameters('onPremDataGateway_name'))]"
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/customApis', parameters('customApis_RemedyConnector_name'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "Test-LogicApp-CustomConnector"
      },
      "properties": {
        "definition": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
          "actions": {
            "Compose_Soap_Envelope": {
              "inputs": "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:FRIntegration\"><soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><urn:OpCreate></urn:OpCreate></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>",
              "runAfter": {
              },
              "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Scope": {
              "actions": {
                "get_all": {
                  "inputs": {
                    "body": "@outputs('Compose_Soap_Envelope')",
                    "headers": {
                      "Content-Type": "text/xml",
                      "SOAPAction": "urn:FRIntegration/OpCreate"
                    },
                    "host": {
                      "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['RemedyPassThrough']['connectionId']"
                      }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/SoapPassThrouh",
                    "queries": {
                      "server": "<server>",
                      "webService": "FRIntegration"
                    },
                    "retryPolicy": {
                      "type": "none"
                    },
                    "authentication": {
                      "type": "Basic"
                    }
                  },
                  "runAfter": {},
                  "type": "ApiConnection"
                }
              },
              "runAfter": {
                "Compose_Soap_Envelope": [
                  "Succeeded"
                ]
              },
              "type": "Scope"
            },
            "Compose": {
              "inputs": {
                "IncidentID": "INC0001",
                "RequestStatus": "Fault Investigation",
                "WorkLogID": "WorkLogID"
              },
              "runAfter": {
                "Scope": [
                  "Succeeded"
                ]
              },
              "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Response": {
              "inputs": {
                "body": "@outputs('Compose')",
                "headers": {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "schema": {
                  "properties": {
                    "incidentID": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "requestStatus": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "workLogID": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  },
                  "type": "object"
                },
                "statusCode": 201
              },
              "kind": "Http",
              "runAfter": {
                "Compose": [
                  "Succeeded"
                ]
              },
              "type": "Response"
            }
          },
          "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
              "defaultValue": {},
              "type": "Object"
            }
          },
          "triggers": {
            "manual": {
              "type": "Request",
              "kind": "Http",
              "inputs": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "workLogId": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "workLogDateTime": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "workLogDescription": {
                          "type": "string"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "method": "POST"
              }
            }
          },
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "outputs": {}
        },
        "parameters": {
          "$connections": {
            "value": {
              "RemedyPassThrough": {
                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connections_RemedyConnector_name'))]",
                "connectionName": "[parameters('connections_RemedyConnector_name')]",
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/customApis', parameters('customApis_RemedyConnector_name'))]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "resources": [
      ],
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/customApis', parameters('customApis_RemedyConnector_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connections_RemedyConnector_name'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've also downloaded and compared the ARM Template for the logic app that i designed in the designer but I don't find any differences. I would appreciate any help/pointers to sort this out.

Thanks
Sanjay

Comment: The only difference i can see is that if i add it via designer, it adds this extra property in the action: "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"

Comment: And I got it to work, if I use the Visual Studio Designer for Logic Apps, I do the same i.e., delete the action, add it again in the designer. Deploy the generated template and everything works !

Comment: Awesome that you got it to work, I one time had to design the logic app in the portal and then export the design from the portal and copy paste it into Visual studio to get it to work. Nice that you got it to work this way.

Comment: Didn't try this myself but will give it a shot. When you exported the template, did it come up with that "authentication" property? Did you find any different between the template you exported and the one you had before?